# compare two dates and second date should be greater than first date in php

Tags: php, validation

Hi guys i am trying to compare two dates from date and to date. TO Date shoudl be greater than from date.
I didn't get any idea of how to do validation for that in php. Can anyone help me how can we do that.

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="downloadreport.php">

                            <div class="col-md-12" >
                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <label class="control-label">From  Date</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" > 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <label class="control-label">To Date</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker1" > 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-info form-control">Download Report</button>
                                </div>
                       </div>
                        </form>
```

Downalodreport.php

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fromdate =$_POST['datepicker'];
    $todate = $_POST['datepicker1'];
    $usertype= $_POST['trackforums'];


    //my code will start
}
```

Can anyone help me how to do that

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can u dump your $_POST show us your inputs ?

Comment: sure give me 2 mins

Comment: string(10) "2018-07-01" string(10) "2018-07-31"  getting results like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
<?php

    $fromdate = strtotime($_POST['datepicker']);
    $todate = strtotime($_POST['datepicker1']);

    if ($todate > $fromdate ) {
        echo 'Todate is higher!';
    } else {
        echo 'Fromdate is higher!';
    }

    ?>
```

U can learn more about `strtotime` function [here](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: i just want to check only second date should be higher than first date

Comment: can i write like this  if($fromdate > $todate)

Comment: Yeah but u need to use strtotime.

Comment: i have field like this  $duedate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['duedate'])); i want to check that $duedate value should be in future value only.how can i do validation for that

Comment: I'm not sure i understood u, but u want to check if date (duedate) is higher from now ? U can use `$now = strtotime(date('Y-m-d') ` which will return u date now and use  `if ($now < $duedate) {... `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176387/discussion-between-suresh-and-morganfreefarm).

Comment: hi i got more problem can i ask

Comment: Come in chat :)

Comment: i have one doubt may i ask

Answer (score 1):

If both date has a standard format, you can use the strtotime function to compare them.
It will convert the date into a unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970).